# Flutter error in Enum after importing the Enum into another Flutter application

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code in a Flutter application:

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'saving_goal_status.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 3)
enum SavingGoalStatus {
  @HiveField(0)
  done,
  @HiveField(1)
  todo,
  @HiveField(2)
  fail,
  @HiveField(3)
  paid,
}
```

This code is working fine. However when I import the Flutter application into another Flutter application I receive errors in the imported code. The error I get is "**IDENTIFIER expected, got '@'** In all applications I have the Hive packages in the pubspec.yaml. But it seems to have problems with the HiveFields. In the attached image the errors are shown.

[image: IDENTIFIER expected, got @]

Does anyone have a clue? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe a different Flutter and therefore different (older) Dart version is used, that doesn't support @metadata on enums or enum fields? This is just a guess though.

Comment: Thanks for the response Thomas. Unfortunately it does not fix it. Tried your suggestion by creating two new applications but the problem is still there.

Comment: Try `flutter clean` restart the IDE and `flutter pub get`. Also check the version you are using, I'm not facing this issue on latest version.

Comment: Tried to clean the projects, restarted IDE, but problem is still there. Fixed it with a workaround. Once the Hive classes are generated it is safe to comment the annotations. Now, compile issues are gone.